# Tkinter button that returns its col-row values

Tags: python, tkinter

I need my buttons to return their column and row values when clicked.
I've tried to code but not worked.

```
my_button = ttk.Button(mainframe)
my_button['command'] = return_func(my_button.grid_info()['row'])
my_button.grid(column=1, sticky=(W, E))
```

I'm creating buttons automaticly, so col and row values are changing.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `return_func(inpt.grid_info()['row'])`, you are executing `return_func` with that argument. You don't want to do this.

Instead, use `lambda: return_func(inpt.grid_info()['row'])` to create a container function for your function call. That way, the `lambda` function executes your function when it is called.

Another way of doing this would be like so:

```
def command_function():
  return_func(inpt.grid_info()['row'])

my_button['command'] = command_function
```

I haven't worked with `tk` enough to tell if you need to pass in an argument, so that might also be a problem for you.